# about implicit constructor creation?

Tags: c++, constructor

it's well knows that compiler implicitly creates an constructor but
if we have a code like this:

```
class A
{
    public:
       A(int = 0) {}

};
```

this constructor is default one and conversion operator in same time.

**Question:**

will compiler generate "empty" default constructor `A() {}` anyway as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. A default constructor is one that has no arguments or arguments with default values.

So, basically, you already defined the default constructor.

Section `12.1.5` from `C++03` states this:

> A default constructor for a class X is a constructor of class X that
>   can be called without an argument. [...]

As you can call your constructor without an argument, it is a default one. Ergo, the compiler doesn't need to declare another.

Comment: @ildjarn the copy of the standard that I have :). It's from 2005. Is that wrong?

Comment: There were standards in 1998, 2003, and 2011; I'm curious at what you might be looking at that's from 2005.

Comment: @ildjarn Oh... it's a working draft. Regardless, it's still valid :)

Answer (score 0):

No, as you've declared an explicit constructor, the compiler won't generate a parameter-less (is that a word?!?) default.

And given that your constructor has a default parameter value, were you to instantiate the class like this:

```
void main()
{
    A myA;
}
```

your explicit constructor would be called..